# C# Sql Server array access confusion

Tags: sql, arrays, boolean, bitvector

I'm attempting to efficiently store and access a boolean value (to represent 'availability') for thousands of people on my SQL Server Database. They'll give me dates for when they're unavailable and I need to represent them and programatically process them against a schedule.

In other words, I need to be able to track each day of the year's availability for each person (a simple Yes/No or True/False will suffice).

I came across the Bitvector32 structure and got it to work wonderfully (see link for background: [How do I convert a SQL Server 'Int' field to 'BitVector32' within my C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516510/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-int-field-to-bitvector32-within-my-c-sharp-pro) ). I'm able to create it, write it as an int to my DB, and recover it back into my C# program.

The problem is, I'd like to be able to access the boolean value contained within this structure via SQL but I can't do it.

My next option is to create an array of boolean values (24 occurrences would work) only for the specified dates I need at the time and store this in my sql server table to contain the Y/N for each person. However, being new to this, I'm hearing that SQL Server doesn't handle arrays. The only option is to define 24 uniquely named 'bit' fields in SQL Server and load them from my C# boolean array. This seems ugly.

Does anyone see a better solution or am I close?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports bitwise operators. `Bitvector32` uses the usual bitwise arithmetic "tricks" to access bits. `bits & 1` gives you bit 0, for example. `bits | 1` sets bit 0.

Comment: This worked wonderfully - I didn't know anything about the bitwise operators and spent a little time finding the perfect solution. thanks usr!